# Размер индекса в InnoDB, допускающий NULL (MySQL сервер)

Tags: mysql, innodb

Подскажите пожалуйста, находил ли кто-нибудь в доке MySQL подтверждение, что для InnoDB, колонка, которая допускает NULL будет в индексе занимать на 1 байт больше.

Пример: создаю колонку `SMALLINT UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL;` (2 байта).
В индексе будет занимать 3 байта (без учета хвоста в виде PK).

Такая же колонка, не допускающая NULL: `SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL;` в индексе будет как и положено занимать 2 байта.

Comment: при чём здесь индекс? индекс — это просто дерево из ссылок на записи... в нём хоть `char(255)` хоть `TINYINT` будут занимать одинаково места...

Comment: Ты абсолютно не прав. В доке почитай что это такое и как работает.

Comment: Sql-INDEX (в терминологии InnoDB *вторичные индекс*) — это просто B-дерево с первичными ключами хранящимися в листьях [\[1\]](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-index-types.html). Так что абсолютно не важно на значениях какого размера он построен...

Comment: Почитай про то, как в InnoDB B+ Tree работает. Не мешай чувак, я тут жду помощи экспертов.

Comment: '_Не мешай чувак, я тут жду помощи экспертов_'. При таком подходе вы никогда не дождетесь ответа... Тем более, что при вашей формулировке вопроса выходит, что колонка полностью находится в индексе. Что конечно не так, там находятся только значения ключей, которых при не уникальном индексе меньше, чем записей в таблице. Вот если бы вы спрашивали про длину ключей в узлах дерева ...

Comment: И у MySQL дока очень слабая, там много нет и это многое надо смотреть экспериментальным путем и изучением исходников

Comment: Вопрос простой - если колонка NULL допускает, в неуникальном (для простоты) индексе (!) она будет занимать дополнительный байт информации или нет. Экспериментальным путем я выяснил - да, места занимает индекс больше, НО не нашел официального подтверждения этому(

Comment: В индексе находятся значения, которые вы индексируете и ссылки на PK, если на то пошло. На ютубе есть доклад Петра Зайцева по теме, советую)

Comment: Ну и если вы экспериментировали, то посмотрите в hex-редакторе на страницы индекса, найдите чем они отличаются. А от документации MySQL вы таких подробностей не дождетесь

Comment: "Только если у вас есть миллион записей с значением ключа "abc", то у вас в дереве один раз лежит значение "abc" и далее список указателей." вот это не считаю правильным. Читал про совершенно другое хранение. Есть ссылки на пруфы этой информации?...

В доке ток это нашел: "Due to the key storage format, the key length is one greater for a column that can be NULL than for a NOT NULL column."

Но тут непонятно: это EXPLAIN так мне рисует Key_len или же реально в индексе +1 байт)

Comment: Мда, mysql меня продолжает поражать ... посмотрел структуру индексных блоков... Он действительно умудряется повторять значение ключа для каждой записи. буквально в виде ключ-ссылка, ключ-ссылка (не считая внутрииндексных указателей)

Comment: А как смотрел структуру можешь описать?) Какие инструменты юзаешь) А то я внутрь не лазил, видимо надо начинать)

Comment: Создал таблицу.добавил 4 записи 'abc'. посмотрел в Far файл в hex режиме. создал индекс на поле с данными. Еще раз посмотрел. Правда он умудрился страницу индекса два раза в файл положить, но это видимо особенности процесса его построения. Потому, что после добавления еще пары записей они добавились только в одну из индексных страниц, а вторая не изменилась - значит она просто грязь от процесса построения